# "constructor JSONParser in class JSONParser cannot be applied to given types" error occured

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I am trying to build a weather app in Java language and Netbeans(As IDE). The code is as follows:

```
URL link = new URL("http://api.dataweave.in/v1/weather/findByCity/?api_key=a93abfaea2a98410be0df095f72df25d7a5d5eb5&city=Shimla&date=20130501");
URLConnection uc1 = link.openConnection();
BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc1.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder weather = new StringBuilder();
weather.append(in1.readLine() + "\n");
String line="0";

while ((line = in1.readLine()) != null) {
    weather.append(line + "\n");
}

String result=weather.toString();
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(result);
JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray) obj.get("data");

System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("city"));
System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("country"));
System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("min_today"));
System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("max_today"));
System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("desc_today"));
System.out.println(((JSONObject) jarr.get(0)).get("date"));
```

On the Line

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(result);
```

I am getting this error:

```
constructor JSONParser in class JSONParser cannot be applied to given types
required: Source, Error Manager
found: No arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments list differs in length
```

I already have "json-simple" jar file as a library. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your import statements. You will be importing it from jdk.nashorn.
The code you are trying to attempt is from org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Answer (score 5):

**Remove** `import jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.jsonparser;`

**Add** `import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;`